# How to know if a window has gone?

Tags: c#, windows

I would like to know if I can get any message to say that a particular open window has gone ?

Clearify: I open a notepad, type in some text, then I close it. I would like my C# program to display a message to state that my window has gone. I am new to C# so please suggest a class or classes I may need to look into, or better provide a short sample to demonstrate the main task. I am very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty but working way will be to poll the currently running processes with a Timer, comparing the list with the processes that were running in the previous polling you made.

First, add such class member to store the processes for comparing later:

```
List<string> lastRunningProcesses = new List<string>();
```

Then, to start polling have such code:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 500; //half a second
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Start();
```

And finally this is the polling and comparing code:

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> currentlyRunningProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().ToList().ConvertAll(p => p.ProcessName);
    if (lastRunningProcesses.Count > 0)
    {
        List<string> closedProcesses = lastRunningProcesses.FindAll(p => !currentlyRunningProcesses.Contains(p));
        if (closedProcesses.Count > 0)
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} process(es) have been closed:\n{1}", closedProcesses.Count, string.Join("\n", closedProcesses)));
    }
    lastRunningProcesses = currentlyRunningProcesses;
}
```

As long as your application will run, it will keep polling.

Answer (score 4):

As @Richard points out you need `FindWindow()` to watch *any* Window. In the case of Notepad you can do it more simply, since the notepad *process* is terminated as soon as the window is gone.

You can start notepad with `Process.Start()` and use the `Exited` event on the returned `Process` object to run code when notepad is finished:

```
Process notepad = Process.Start("Notepad", "c:\temp\text.txt");
notepad.Exited += MyExitEventHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not going to start notepad from the program itself, I mean to check all open windows, then the one that is closed is gone. I think your solution to handling exit event looks very promising. I will try it out, again thank Anders a lot.

Comment: If you can work on *process* level (which means you don't want to watch when e.g. dialogues within a program are closed) you can use `Process.GetProcesses` to get a list of all currently running processes.

Comment: Of course this relies on the process only having one window such that the closure of the window is synonymous with the termination of the process. But if you can guarantee that then using the process is simpler

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use interop to do this. Create a timer that calls the [FindWindow win32 function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

When this stops finding the window then the window has gone

Comment: busy wait is a very bad way to handle locks.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and suggestions

Comment: @none locks? Which locks are you referring to?

Comment: @richard if you think about it , you open a thread that is waiting for another process to finish, before the thread can continue. isn't that the definition of lock?

Comment: Well if that's what I was suggesting that would be a pretty expensive way to do it - but that isn't what I said. I said to put it on a timer. The timer simply fires (maybe a thread pool timer or a WM_TIMER timer - the OP doesn't state whether this is running from a UI based app) and checks for the window. If the window is gone then it signals the rest of the app (sets a ManualResetEvent(Slim) or fires a .NET event